# Want to push python file from Azure Repo to Databricks Workspace Using CICD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

I want to push the Python file from Azure Repo to Databricks Workspace using Azure DevOps (CICD), but when I am trying to push the same into the Databricks workspace it is converting the same python file into notebook, but I don't want the same.

I want that file to be the python file only.

Comment: Hi @SheikhMubashir, may i know if there's any update? You can check the reply below, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

To push a Python file from an Azure Repo to a Databricks Workspace without converting it to a notebook using Azure DevOps, you need to change your deployment method. The traditional deployment method depends on the Workspace REST API, which doesn't support arbitrary files.

Instead, you should have a repo in your destination workspace and update that repo via the [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/en/archive/dev-tools/cli/repos-cli.html#update-a-repo-to-the-most-recent-commit-of-a-remote-branch-or-to-a-tag).

Yaml sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: configuredatabricks@0
  inputs:
    url: '$(DATABRICKS_HOST)'
    token: '$(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)'

- script: |
    echo "Checking out the branch"
    databricks repos update --path /Repos/xxxx@xxx.com/yourreponame --branch "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
  env:
    DATABRICKS_HOST: $(DATABRICKS_HOST)
    DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)
  displayName: 'Update databricks repository'
```

The pipeline :
[image]

The python file on databricks workspace repo:

[image]

You can check the [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687643/how-can-i-deploy-arbitrary-files-from-an-azure-git-repo-to-a-databricks-workspac) for more details.